# Assign a HTML Button with a value to PHP

Tags: php, html, button

Hi do anyone know how to Assign a value to a "Submit" type button on HTML to the PHP process?
Currently the user needs to click a button which would then assign a global variable a value. etc. button 1 = 10, button 2 = 30... Attached are the codes that I have typed in so far. Please help! Thanks!

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test </title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Test Generator</h2>
    <p>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="2 Weeks"/>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="1 Month"/></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="3 Months" /></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="6 Months" /></p>
    <p>
        <input type="submit" name="action" value="1 Year" /></p>

<?php

    $dateSelection;

    switch ($_POST['action']) 
    {
        case '2 Weeks':
            $dateSelection==1;
        break;
        case '1 Month':
            $dateSelection==2;
        break;
        case '3 Months':
            $dateSelection==3;
        break;
        case '6 Months':                    
            $dateSelection==4;
        break;
        case '1 Year':
            $dateSelection==5;
        break;
        default:
            echo "Something is wrong...";
        break;
    }
?>

</body>
```

Thanks!

Comment: value="<?php echo $dateSelection ?>"

Comment: `value="<?= $dateSelection ?>"`

Comment: @FerozAkbar Okay, please tell me. I used to give answers with <?= $somevar ?> and got hated on because using short tags and all is bad and a bad habit. Yet I see people using them all the time. Does it really matter that much? And basically all servers have short tags enabled right?

Comment: @RiggsFolly "No not all" Do you mean that I should just focus on <?php echo instead of <?= just to be rather safe than sorry?

Comment: I dont understand the above codes... sorry Im new to php and HTML. I posted more information at below comments. Thanks.

Comment: You should make a form with `action="somefile.php" method="post"` and when you click the submit button in that form it will send you to `somefile.php`. Then you can retrieve the data from the previous page by using: $somevar = $_POST['action']; where $somevar will contain the value from the button in yuor form

Comment: I submitted an answer to give you better help

Comment: @Déjàvu If you use just `<?php ... ?>` it will work anywhere. If you use `<? .. ?>` it will only work in short_tags are turned on. Its a no brainer surely.

Comment: @RiggsFolly Don't get me wrong I know whether my short tags are enabled or not. But I was talking about SO only. If i post an asnwer with <? .. ?> I used to get a lot of hate comments because I "can't know if someone has short tags enabled" or not. That's why i started to answer with <?php .. ?> instead.

Comment: @Déjàvu Yes but my point is if you move your site from one host to another for some reason, or use some of your code on multiple site, you can never be TOTALLY sure short tags are going to be on. So dont risk it.

Comment: What about using a hidden value tag. Then associating it to the name of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make a form.

```
<form id="someform" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] ; ?>">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="1 year">
    <input type="submit" name="action" value="2 year">
</form>
```

Then add php code on the same page at the bottom:

```
<?php
    echo $_POST['action'];
?>
```

Now if you load the page (it will show an error for now that's it not assigned) now click one of your buttons. It should show 1 or 2 years depending on what button you clicked.

If this is what you mean with your question i will help you further and remove errors and help you send it to another page if you want.

Comment: I'd recommend against the use of "PHP_SELF" and instead, for the use of the "REQUEST_URI" as the use of PHP_SELF mitigates all rewrites you might have (now or in the future). If you then need to remove the query string, try: strstr($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']) ?: $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

Comment: @SEoF Yeah, you're right. I knew it was something else but I couldn't think of it that soon (im not at all experienced in php) so this was the first thing i knew that would work. But you're right. It's a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You could try putting the submit buttons inside a label for a radio button...

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST['action']) {
    echo $_POST['action'],' weeks selected';
}
?>

<style>
.hidden-radio{display:none;}
</style>

<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="radio" name="action" value="2" id="2_weeks" class="hidden-radio" />
    <label for="2_weeks"><input type="submit" value="2 Weeks"/></label>

    <input type="radio" name="action" value="4" id="4_weeks" class="hidden-radio" />
    <label for="4_weeks"><input type="submit" value="1 Month"/></label>

    <input type="radio" name="action" value="13" id="13_weeks" class="hidden-radio" />
    <label for="13_weeks"><input type="submit" value="3 Months"/></label>

    <input type="radio" name="action" value="26" id="26_weeks" class="hidden-radio" />
    <label for="26_weeks"><input type="submit" value="6 Months"/></label>

    <input type="radio" name="action" value="52" id="52_weeks" class="hidden-radio" />
    <label for="52_weeks"><input type="submit" value="1 Year"/></label>
</form>
```

Comment: The button is required as after the user clicks on the button the script would bring the user to another page. And the button would actually contain a date variable.

Comment: The button is still there, only now, the "action" variable is set by radio buttons, triggered by labels, triggered by clicking on the submit. Try the code above. I haven't included the values you wanted as "10", "20" and so on don't logically make sense for "2 Weeks", "1 Month" and "3 months", so you'll need to modify them in the radio buttons

Comment: When I tested the codes I see the radio buttons right beside the submit buttons. The variables that I gave as an example dont have to be the values etc. 10, 30.

Comment: Yup, you'll need to hide them with some CSS. I'll update the answer.

Comment: If you let me know the values for the 5 inputs, I'll put them in the answer too...